# The entire thing

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge

She gave to me:

```
121 ARMIES 
27 HARDNESS 
73 RELUCTANT 
86 SEE 
459 SNORE 
196 OPENS 
34 OINKING 
587 GOLEM 
153 LAB FEE 
616 HELMET 
118 LEGEND 
12 BEE TURRET 
169 ABORT 
93 NATURE 
126 MAGMA 
30 AND IRON 
300 KITTY 
139 AROMAS 
44 LOGO 
116 HORSE 
551 NAILED 

You must get the entire thing.
```

---

<sub>Apparently this puzzle does not meet the quality standards for a question, so this text is here to trick the StackExchange bot. It is just a filler for now and I may edit the question later. This is not part of the puzzle.</sub>

Comment: By the way, backsolving from the answer, horse can be replaced by shore to enhace difficulty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> These are partial anagrams of Pokemon names. and the numbers correspond to the pokemon. I'm assuming that the missing letters are the desired answers to each step.
>  121 ARMIES = Starmie T
>  27 HARDNESS = Sandshrew W
>  73 RELUCTANT = Tentacruel E
>  86 SEE = Seel L
>  459 SNORE = Snover V
>  196 OPENS = Espeon E
>  34 OINKING = Nidoking D
>  587 GOLEM = Emolga A
>  153 LAB FEE = Bayleef Y
>  616 HELMET = Shelmet S
>  118 LEGEND = Goldeen O
>  12 BEE TURRET = Butterfree F
>  
>  169 ABORT = Crobat C
>  93 NATURE = Haunter H
>  126 MAGMA = Magmar = R
>  30 AND IRON = Nidorina I
>  300 KITTY = Skitty S
>  139 AROMAS = Omastar T
>  44 LOGO = Gloom M
>  116 HORSE = Horsea A
>  551 NAILED = Sandile S
>  Twelve Days of Christmas

Comment: Wow, you deduced that conundrum quick! Congrats to you, good sir/madam.